# phpmyadmin displayed undesired content after installing and editing config file

Tags: apache2, phpmyadmin

Initially last evening my PhpMyAdmin was working. But today I came to the office and checked it and it was not working.

The error was: `phpmyadmin not found`.

Then I tried certain steps as mentioned below:

1. removed PHP and installed it again.
2. updated the config file

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
   ```
3. edited the config file

   ```
   Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf
   ```

After doing this I tried to access PhpMyAdmin through `localhost/phpmyadmin` and I got this displayed on my browser:

[image]

[image]

Please, could you help me getting my PhpMyAdmin back?

Comment: Did you install the PHP module for Apache?  Something as:  `sudo apt install libapache2-mod-php7.0`; `sudo a2enmod php7.0`. Please tag your PHP and Ubuntu version.

Comment: my php version is 7.0 and ubuntu 16.10 yakkety yak

Comment: On my system, I disabled the PHP module for Apache and the content looks different. Apparently this is different problem. How actually you have installed PhpMyAdmin?